# How to properly install GPU card on HP DL380 Server?

Tags: installation, hp-proliant

I'm not very sure if my question are related with this community, so if it is not, please vote for off-topic, and I will delete it.

Our lab just bought a Nvidia Tesla P100 and HP Proliant DL380 Gen9 server, but unfortunately no ones here knows how to install that GPU card into the server.

So, I've tried, but it doesn't end well, my questions and problems are:

1. Shown in the 3 pictures, was I doing a correct physical installation? Am I using the right cable for powering the GPU? The default cable in Tesla box is the double one shown in 4th picture, but I don' know how or where to use it.
2. We've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in the server before. It was normal. But after installed the GPU card, when entering Ubuntu (user login page), the fan ensembles are screaming, and never stopped! That was the most scary and unpleasant sound I've ever heard, gooseflesh all over. We're afraid breaking or burning the server, so we shut it down. So, I guess we're not properly installing the GPU card?
3. The Tesla P100 was installed on PCI slot 5, In BIOS, it was shown as Video Controller, is that normal?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One note about the noise: We have servers which have 4 P100 cards installed. When one of the servers is turned on or rebootet for a couple of seconds the scream of the fans is audible outside of the server room (through closed doors) and on the other end of the corridor (about 45m). So I'd consider the noise level as normal, but not the duration. It should go down after the BIOS POST phase.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks, The fan wil go up when BIOS POST, and go down, it's normal. But will go up again when entering Ubuntu login page, and will not stop, thats what worry me.

Comment: That sounds more like a driver issue to me. If the card was installed incorrectly I'd expect the fans to run high the whole time.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider BTW, which cable do you think I should use for powering the GPU card? is that white cable in the picture correct?